# Trying to build trie with classes in python - strange behavior

Tags: python, class, trie

I'm trying to implement trie in python. I'm using dictionaries+classes instead of lists (I know it's not optimal, but I'm just trying to make it work at all).

After debugging I found out that **each layer has all letters in dictionary. I cannot understand why.**

Here is my code (implementation is 100% most basic, straightforward):

```
class lttr:
    finish = 0
    pointers = {}  #for letters to reference class instance

eps = lttr()

def add(word):
    global eps
    last = eps
    for ind,x in enumerate(word):
        if last.pointers.get(x,None):
            last = last.pointers[x]
        else:
            last.pointers[x] = lttr()
            last=last.pointers[x]
    last.finish=1

def lookup(word):
    global eps
    last=eps
    for ind,x in enumerate(word):
        if last.pointers.get(x,None):
            last=last.pointers[x]
        else:
            return False
    return bool(last.finish)

add("pear")
print lookup("ar")  #prints True ... but why?
```

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but did you know? variables declared inside a class are shared amongst all instances of that class. Modify one lttr's `pointers`, and every other lttrs' `pointers` will also be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you intended for each individual `lttr` instance to have its own unique values for `finish` and `pointers`. In which case, you need to declare them as attributes of `self` inside `__init__`, rather than just defining them at the class scope.

```
class lttr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.finish = 0
        self.pointers = {}  #for letters to reference class instance
```

Now your script will print `False` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your lttr class has class variables, but you want instance variables. Class variables are unique across all instances of that class, so you only have one `pointers` object.

```
class lttr:
    finish = 0
    pointers = {}  #for letters to reference class instance
```

What you want is

```
class lttr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.finish = 0
        self.pointers = {}
```

and that works as expected.